# python : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, numpy, model, pickle

I want to build a model data using this code :

```
def modeldata(filename, ratingMatrix):
result={}
itemmatrix = matrixconvert(ratingMatrix)
current = 0
total = len(itemmatrix)

for item in itemmatrix:
    current+=1
    if current%100--0: print ("%d / %d" % (current,total))

    result[item] = neighbor
    #print result

with open(filename+".csv", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(result, f)
```

filename variable is a data result from clustering process that contains userid, itemid, and rating, 
`then ratingMatrix is a dictionary which contains key (user), subkey(item) and rating

```
10 dict 1 {'255': 3.0}
```

. Neighbor contains a similarity data.

```
0 tuple 2 (1.0, '9790')
```

I want to build a model data using those things above, I run the function with this code

```
modeldata(filename, ratingMatrix)
```

but, I get this error :

```
1 / 306
.
.
304 / 306
305 / 306
306 / 306
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-5af8931a8f1e>", line 1, in <module>
    modeldata(filename, ratingMatrix)

  File "<ipython-input-28-220883448026>", line 14, in modeldata
    with open(filename+".txt", "wb") as f:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong with this code ? where is the error from, and how can I make it work?

Thank you for your help....

Comment: Can I see what your filename variable is being declared as? It doesn't like the string concatenation on your `open` line

Comment: sorry it's csv, I've updated the code. But I still get that error... :(

Comment: @etsu     well `filename` wants to be a string, but looks like its a numpy array? And is there a particular reason your opening the file in binary mode?

Comment: Please try using [this tool](https://github.com/alexmojaki/askso) to make your question clearer.

Comment: @ScottStainton No, it's just for opening that file. Ok, I'll try to read `filename` not as array and change it to be a string. thx

Comment: I guess its stated pretty obviously in the question, `filename` doesn't contain a filename but `"filename variable is a data result from clustering process that contains userid, itemid, and rating"` (probably an intermediate result before the version you want to save ?). So choose an appropriate filename according to your clustering operation and use it to name your result file ?

Comment: Also I guess that you won't have a "human-readable" output file using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) serialization (but only the `result` object serialized on your disk for a later reopening with `pickle` module). Maybe you can take a look to `csv` (or why not `json`) module from the standard library for what your are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you getting is within the modeldata function and more specifically the opening statement for writing to a file. The error is stating that you can't add using the "+" a string ".txt" to "numpy.ndarray" which looks like it is coming from the variable filename. Make sure your filename variable is the actual file name you want to write to and not numpy array.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the portion of the code where the filename variable is declared ?